# Can still see cancelled subscriptions from the in-app billing API

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I have created an in-app billing test subscription for my app and the current status of the subscription is "paymentpending" by debugging the code. The trouble is I can no longer see the subscription from Google Play in order to cancel it. I can see that the auto-renew property is set to false and that the subscription should have expired by looking at the purchase date, but the subscription still remains.

How can I cancel/remove the subscription?

Comment: If you do a get https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get can't to see the subscritionId ?